# Comment validation errors to show on node?

Tags: comments, redirection, forms

I am trying to get comment validation errors to show on the node that it was posted from. I know that the comment form action on the node points to the comment URL itself, but I would like it to redirect back to the node to show any validation errors at the top of the node instead of at the top of the add comment page.